# Bootstrap v5 modal show issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I decided to go ahead and update my site to the latest version of Bootstrap, version 5.0 and am having difficulty getting modals to work. Reading the migration guide said nothing about breaking modals and my site worked perfectly before. My code uses javascript/jQuery to fire off the modal after the ajax loads the text. The ajax part still works fine, but it's not firing the modal after it retrieves it. I'm using the latest bootstrap.bundle.min.js.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.hourModal').click(function(){
    var obj_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax-multi.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {obj_id: obj_id,role:'some_role'},
        //dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){ 
            $('.modal-body').html(response);
            //$('#hourModal').modal('show'); //Old way that worked great
            var hourModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('hourModal'));
            hourModal.show(); // New way I tried from the Bootstrap documentation
        }
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm py-0 me-1 hourModal" data-id="1">Blocks</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="hourModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Object Times</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">  </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: BACKDROP: Option "rootElement" provided type "null" but expected type "element".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
As described below, I had to move bootstrap.min.js to the end of the page, after `</body>` and leave where I call jquery.min.js at the top in the header. Anyone have any idea why it has to be done this way?

Comment: You are mixing php and JS which is never a good idea.

Answer (score 12):

Move your `<script>`  with bootstrap at the end of the `<body>`. It fixed my Bootstrap 5 modal issue.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is fixed in currently available 5.0.1

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

Fixed in Bootstrap 5.0.1

---

I had the same problem. The only difference I use Webpack to build.

If you want to load your scripts from `head` section you can try to add `async` option.

This fixed the issue for me.

```
<script src="..." async="async"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I called jquery.js and bootstrap.js at the end of the html and before /body and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

mamantoha's suggestion seems to be the better way to handle this since it doesn't require moving the  outside the  section, and some people may have dependencies that require bootstrap to be loaded ahead of other scripts in the  section.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 or 5 you maybe forgetting the '#' in

```
data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
```